# Dart & Flutter: How to wait for request result

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to fetch dictionaries from internet before user will be able to use my application.
I have a logon screen and then user is redirected to form where dropdown lists are populated and used.
The problem occurs from time to time, when requests aren't completed yet due them asynchronous nature but view is already rendered.
Is there any smart way, to wait for http requests?

Comment: Use async/await https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async. So at first fetch users after login, and only after this show form with dropdowns.

Comment: Almost same example is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52094540/5305962

Comment: see [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) documentation

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is probably to initially direct to a loading screen and navigate to the screen showing content in the callback from your server call.

Alternatively you could also handle that within the same screen with a loading state.

Examples see [here](https://flutterbyexample.com/set-up-app-loading/) or [here](http://cogitas.net/custom-loading-animation-flutter/).