# Creating a dropdown from get data

Tags: flutter

I'm just learning flutter, and I'm trying to create a dropdown from post data. Right now I'm just using the public jsonplaceholder api, but will move this over to a private api once I can figure out how it works. When I run my code it is giving this error:

`"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . \nEither zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"`

I've tried a couple of different ways of passing the data into the DropdownMenuItem field with no luck.

here is the code I'm running, it is pretty simple:

````
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: "Hospital Management",
  home: MyApp(),
));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _mySelection = "";

  final String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  List data = []; //edited line

  Future<String> getSWData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);

    setState(() {
      data = resBody;
    });

    print(resBody);

    return "Sucess";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getSWData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hospital Management"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new DropdownButton(
          items: data.map((item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: new Text(item['name']),
              value: item['id'].toString(),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String? newVal) {
            setState(() {
              _mySelection = newVal!;
            });
          },
          value: _mySelection,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```

Feel free to critique any part of my code, like I said, I'm brand new to flutter and still learning the ropes.
````

Comment: If you get API data in dropdown refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210)]

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I looked at your answer, and your code looks almost identical to my code, but it still isn't working. I made the couple of changes to match it up, but it didn't work. Any other thoughts on why this might not be working?

Comment: Hello @Alex Childs Please check my answer hope your problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found why my code wasn't working. so for anyone looking in the future, I have null safety enabled, so I tried to initialize my select holder, called `_mySelection` above, to an empty string, but that wasn't found in the database. By using `String? _mySelection` I could allow the value to be null, and so there was no error when the list was first loaded, and then you can pick an option from the list.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope it help to you.

Create your API Call function and variable declaration and
check your selected name of Id on console

```
  String userId;
  List data = List();
  String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  //your all api call
  Future fetchData() async {
    var result = await http.get(url, headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    var jsonData = json.decode(result.body);
    print(jsonData);
    setState(() {
      data = jsonData;
    });
    return jsonData;
  }
  //call your API fetchData() inside initState()
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }
```

Create your Dropdown Widget

```
    DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: userId,
          hint: Text("Select Name",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          items: data.map((list) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(list['name']),
              value: list['id'].toString(),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              userId = value;
              print(userId);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Your Dropdown look like -> [image]