# fetch a list JSON to a DropdownMenuItem?

Tags: flutter, api, fetch-api, display

I have a JSON object here:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "countryName": "India"
    },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "countryName": "USA"
    }
  ],
  "exceptionInfo": null,
  "message": null,
  "messages": null,
  "isSuccess": true
}
```

I want to fetch the name parameter under data to a DropDownMenuList. I have a data model here:

```
import 'dart:convert';

GetCountry getCountryFromJson(String str) => GetCountry.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String getCountryToJson(GetCountry data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class GetCountry {
  GetCountry({
    this.data,
    this.exceptionInfo,
    this.message,
    this.messages,
    this.isSuccess,
  });

  List<CountryModal> data;
  dynamic exceptionInfo;
  dynamic message;
  dynamic messages;
  bool isSuccess;

  factory GetCountry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetCountry(
    data: List<CountryModal>.from(json["data"].map((x) => CountryModal.fromJson(x))),
    exceptionInfo: json["exceptionInfo"],
    message: json["message"],
    messages: json["messages"],
    isSuccess: json["isSuccess"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "exceptionInfo": exceptionInfo,
    "message": message,
    "messages": messages,
    "isSuccess": isSuccess,
  };
}

class CountryModal {
  CountryModal({
    this.id,
    this.countryName,
  });

  int id;
  String countryName;

  factory CountryModal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CountryModal(
    id: json["id"],
    countryName: json["countryName"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "countryName": countryName,
  };
}
```

The function to fetch the data is below and is the indifferent file:

```
Future<GetCountry> Getcountry(String authToken) async{
    try {
      String uriParts = apiEndPoint.getUriParts('location/GetCountries');
      var response = await http.get(
        apiEndPoint.getHTTPUri(uriParts),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Authorization': authToken
        },
      );
      var responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      GetCountry country = GetCountry.fromJson(responseJson);
      return country;
    }
    catch (err) {
      debugPrint(err.toString());
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

This method fetches the item successfully into a ListView.builder widget but I am a bit lost on how to fetch this to a List<DropdownMenuItem> items.
I have tried going through solutions but nothing seems to work for me.
please help.

EDIT:-
Below is the code for the dropdown list -:

```
  List<CountryModal> _countrylist = [];
String mycountry;

 DropdownButton(
                items: _countrylist.map((item) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: new Text(
                      item.countryName,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),
                    value: item.id.toString(),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                hint: Text(
                  "Please select the country",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black45,
                  ),),
                onChanged: (newVal) {
                  setState(() {
                    mycountry = newVal;
                  });
                },
                value: mycountry,
              ),
```

Error message below -:
[image]
[image]

Sample json format -:

```
{
    "error": "0",
    "message": "Succesfully fetched",
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "5df0b94841f0331baf1357bb",
            "stateName": "test group",
        },
        {
            "id": "5df0df507091683d2f1ad0cf",
            "stateName": "new group",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you get data from API and display it into drop-down menu refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: i got error when i called like this.

Comment: what was the error

Comment: "type 'DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' "

Comment: can you share your api url becuase I will check your json structure, can you display your country name in your dropdown

Comment: sorry i can't. sample below 
```
{
    "error": "0",
    "message": "Succesfully fetched",
    "data": [
        {
            "status": true,
            "_id": "5df0b94841f0331baf1357bb",
            "name": "test group",
            "description": "test description",
            "created_date": "2019-12-11T09:39:20.151Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "status": true,
            "_id": "5df0df507091683d2f1ad0cf",
            "name": "new group",
            "created_date": "2019-12-11T12:21:36.283Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: which data do you display in your dropdown? refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68735915/13997210) answer also

Comment: i want to display country name

Answer (score 0):

You will just pass a map.toList() to the items field.

```dart
DropdownButton(items: myGetCountry.map((CountryModal e) { 
    return DropdownMenuItem(child: SomeWidget(e))).toList();
})
```

Comment: what is "myGetCountry" here?

Comment: after using this i got error -: "type 'DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' "

Comment: I would need to see the whole code to help you further.

Comment: so how can i do that? can I mail you?

Comment: You can edit your question with the code, or post it on a paste website like control-v or pastebin and share the link.

Comment: i am editing the dropdown menu code too here.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. May I have the full error message?

Comment: The value fields are being repeated. There are multiple items with the value of 'India'. And in some cases the value being passed is a countrymodal class.

Comment: so what should I do?