# How to implement DropdownList with JSON data

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I need to display list of `PartnerName` in the dropdown list and when I click `PartnerName` it need to go to respective `Test` of that `PartnerName`.

For now only I'm getting all the partner name in my console. How to display them in my dropdownList and the depending dropdown?

My API function:

```
    Future<List<Partner>> AllPathLab() async {
    var jsonResponse;
  
      var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://MyUrlhssjsjjsd),
          body: ({
            
          }));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
        print(jsonResponse);

        AllPathLabTestModel dataModel = allPathLabTestModelFromJson(response.body);
        print(dataModel.partner.length);
        for (final item in dataModel.partner) 
        print(item.partnerName);

        List<Partner> arrData = dataModel.partner; // this "partner" is actual json array of data[]
        return arrData;
      } else {
        print("Wrong URL");
        throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
      }
    
  }
```

My Json response for all partner:

```
{
"Status": "1",
"Message": "",
"Partner": [
    {
        "EncPartnerId": "gtetetetetet",
        "PartnerName": "tetetet"
    },
    {
        "EncPartnerId": "tettet",
        "PartnerName": "tetette"
    },
     ]
}
```

Full code: For now my dropdown displaying the dummy data Im trying to replace them with my Json data

```
 class _MultipleTestBookingState extends State<MultipleTestBooking> {


  void initState(){
  super.initState();
  AllPathLab();
}



  String _selectedDate = DateTime.now().toString();
  final List<String> allLabList = [
    "Select Lab",
    "Abc",
    "Xyz",
  ];
  String selectedLabFromList = "Abc";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var blockSizeHorizontal = (screenWidth / 100);
    var blockSizeVertical = (screenHeight / 100);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text("Booking Information",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal * 5,
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      )),
                  subtitle: Text("Preferred Visit Date"),
                ),
              ),
              //==============================================================================
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 150),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.lightBlue[50],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  ,
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: DateTimePicker(
                    initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
                    type: DateTimePickerType.date,
                    dateLabelText: 'Select Date',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal * 3.5,
                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                      color: Colors.green,
                      letterSpacing: 2.0,
                    ),
                    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                    lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(
                        days: 30)), // This will add one year from current date
                    validator: (value) {
                      return null;
                    },
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedDate = value;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                        _selectedDate = value;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              //==============================================================================

              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  " Select Pathological Lab",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: blockSizeHorizontal * 4.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                      child: DropdownButton<String>(
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.green,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                        value: selectedLabFromList,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedLabFromList = value!;
                          });
                        },
                        items:allLabList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(value),
                            value: value,
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you get data from API and display it into  flutter dropdown refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68735915/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: Yes! I tried it yesterday its showing some error like `sId need to initialize` I believe because the api function  is in initState() the value is not populates in build.. (not sure) I tried with my API to solve it but no luck

Comment: ok sid is like your value you print or store it and its not necessary take value is sid instead you want any value like name ,etc

Comment: [ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/29256a888fd016940faf07ae470d1534 ] I try all possible  way, Try with all of your suggestions.. Its not showing any error in code but in dubug console  `The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#8237b):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'`

Comment: And in my App `Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: "data  != null" : A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.`   I don't even have 378 line of code. Can you please help me out with this  error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**
you can try with the `Future builder`

```
FutureBuilder<List<Partner>>
```

and your items

```
Container(
                      child: FutureBuilder<List<Partner>>(
                        future: AllPathLab(),
                        builder:
                            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.connectionState !=ConnectionState.done) {
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text("Somthing went wrong");
                          }

                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return DropdownButton<Partner>(
                      dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                      underline: SizedBox(),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      items: snapshot.data.map((Partner data) =>
                                               DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                                                 child: Text(data.PartnerName),
                                                 value: data,
                                               )
                                              ).toList(),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                              });
                          },
                              );
                          }
                          return Text("Waiting for Internet Connection");
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: it showing `Undefined name 'items'.`  although if its work how it will act like as a depending dropdown ? can you please look into my full code 
 [https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/2b000d1c620c28308fce6d1979244f74 ]

Comment: please check now

Comment: dropdown button wrap with future builder just not with listBuilder

Comment: @Toujo please have a loo, i updated my answer

Comment: yes! Now In my code not showing any error, but in debug console its showing `A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null`  because of  null safety? or I did something  wrong ?  [ https://gist.github.com/Roy-Tuhin/2b000d1c620c28308fce6d1979244f74 ]

Comment: Text(data.partnerName??"") try with this and response data must decode `jsonDecode(response.body)`

Comment: really appreciate your help, but new error popping every time . This time in debug console `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>?'
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<List<Partner>>
lib\…\PathologicalMultipleBooking\MultipleTestBooking.dart:118`  Nothing much I changed just `Text(data.partnerName??"") ` and `jsonDecode(response.body)` in my api response

Comment: Finally its  working by  `cast making : DropdownMenuItem<Partner>( child: Text("${data.partnerName}"), value: data, ) ).toList().cast<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>( )`