# I want to put my listview inside a dropdownbottom

Tags: flutter, api, listview, dropdown

This data is coming from an API and I would like to put all options inside the dropdown

[image]

can anybody help me? I'm new to flutter and I'm still learning to use

this is my code:

```
class _ApiFipePageState extends State<ApiFipePage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: pegarUsuarios(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var usuario = snapshot.data![index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(usuario['nome']),
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  pegarUsuarios() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas');
    var resposta = await http.get(url);
    if (resposta.statusCode == 200) {
      return jsonDecode(resposta.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('não foi possivel carregar os usuarios');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below answer hope its help to you. you can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68735915/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) also for data comes from API and display it into dropdown.

Declare variables:

```
String? sid;
  List data = [];
  var urls = "https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas";
```

Your API call function:

```
Future fetchData() async {
    var result = await http.get(Uri.parse(urls), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    var jsonData = json.decode(result.body);

    setState(() {
      data = jsonData;
    });
    return jsonData;
  }
```

call your API fetchData() inside initState()

```
@override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Your Dropdown Widget:

```
Container(
                width: 200,
                child: InputDecorator(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      isDense: true,
                      isExpanded: true,
                      value: sid,
                      hint: Text("Select Data",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      items: data.map((list) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(list['nome']),
                          value: list['codigo'].toString(),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          sid = value as String?;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Your result Screen for DropdownButton ->
[image]

Your result Screen for Dropdown -> [image: img]

Comment: what's the point of returning data in the ``fetchData`` function? Make it instead void.

Comment: @OMiShah I cant understand what you say but as per your statement I use `void fetchData` instead of `Future fetchData` or just declare `fetchData` its also work

Comment: what can't you understand? :(  and it will definitely work both ways but it's not about ``it also work`` !!

Comment: Welcome @RogerAraujo upvote my answer thanks,