# Flutter Drop-down selection which populates form fields with JSON data

Tags: json, flutter, dropdown, bloc

Can somebody show an example of how a flutter Drop-down can be populated with JSON objects, which when selected, Fills a form with the JSON objects data? How would this be implemented with the Bloc pattern?

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119873/13997210) for JSON data display to dropdown hope its help to you.

Comment: Hi Ravindra, thanks for your answer but when the user selects a name from the Drop-down I would like it to fill other form fields automatically from the JSON data which I am still not sure how to do. Crucially, I also want to implement it in accordance to the bloc pattern.