# How to selectedItem DropdownSearch with API?

Tags: flutter

This is my Flutter code, I want to add Selected Item in Dropdown Search.

```
DropdownSearch<dynamic>(
  enabled: true,
  dropdownSearchDecoration: const InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Customer",
    hintText: "Pilih Customer",
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  ),
  mode: Mode.BOTTOM_SHEET,
  showSearchBox: true,
  onFind: (text) async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "MY API HERE"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        _getcustomer = data;
      });
    }
    return _getcustomer as List<dynamic>;
  },
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      customer = value['nama'];
      idcustomer = value['id'];
    });
  },
  // selectedItem: 0,
  itemAsString: (item) => (item['nama'] ?? "-"),
  scrollbarProps: const ScrollbarProps(
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    thickness: 7,
  ),
),
```

Can anyone help? Is my code wrong? Please enlighten my friend.

Comment: See [here](https://fluttertpoint.com/searchable-dropdown-flutter). And let me know your issue?

Comment: If I use "Item" I can use "SelectedItem", but if I use "OnFind" I'm confused

Comment: I suggest you to call the API outside the Dropdown in a function. Then assign data to _getcustomer. And call that function in initState(){}. The _getcustomer will get the data on start. Then you can assign the _getcustomer  to  -> item:_getcustomer . No needed to use onFind.

Comment: Then how about writing in "Selected Item: ...?" if using "item:_getcustomer"

Comment: Inside onChange: (value){ selectedItem = value}, Try this.

Comment: If you want search data from dropdown refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528481/13997210) answer hope its help to you.