# Flutter searchable dropdown

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I have a widget in my app that i want to search in a class of fermentables the name of them.
The name renders alright, the search works well, but when i click on them, the controller is not updated, if i save the app on vscode, then it update.

I use Dropdown2 package, i find it easier to implement and found the example code working well.

Here's my code.

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton2(
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text(
                  'Selecione um fermentável',
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium,
                ),
                items: fermentables
                    .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: item.name.toLowerCase(),
                          child: Text(
                            item.name,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
                value: selectedFermentable,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedFermentable = value as String;
                  });
                },
                buttonHeight: 40,
                buttonWidth: 200,
                itemHeight: 40,
                dropdownMaxHeight: 400,
                searchController: fermentableName,
                searchInnerWidgetHeight: 50,
                searchInnerWidget: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 8,
                    bottom: 4,
                    right: 8,
                    left: 8,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    expands: true,
                    maxLines: null,
                    controller: fermentableName,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10,
                        vertical: 8,
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Pesquise um fermentável',
                      hintStyle: textTheme.bodyMedium,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
                  return (item.value
                      .toString()
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(searchValue));
                },
                onMenuStateChange: (isOpen) {
                  if (!isOpen) {
                    fermentableName.clear();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70528481/13997210) or use [dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) package

Comment: Try this one perfect answer https://fluttertpoint.in/searchable-dropdown-flutter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using [dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) its the best dropdown search that i found so far

Answer (score 0):

check out [multi_select_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter) package will help you to achieve your functionality. It will provide wide range of various search functionality in textfield, dropdown and so many...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `controller is not updated`?

I've tested your code and it seems to work fine.

Comment: When i click on a item of the dropdown, the textformfield is not filled with that item

Comment: It's working in my side. You might want to update your question to a full sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropDownSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDownSearch({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.textController,
    required this.items,
  });
  final String title;
  final TextEditingController? textController;
  final List<String>? items;

  @override
  State<DropDownSearch> createState() => _DropDownSearchState();
}

class _DropDownSearchState extends State<DropDownSearch> {
  bool _isTapped = false;
  List<String> _filteredList = [];
  List<String> _subFilteredList = [];

  @override
  initState() {
    _filteredList = widget.items!;
    _subFilteredList = _filteredList;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.title,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Color(0xFF858597)),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: widget.textController,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _filteredList = _subFilteredList
                            .where((element) => element.toLowerCase().contains(
                                widget.textController!.text.toLowerCase()))
                            .toList();
                      });
                    },
                    validator: (val) =>
                        val!.isEmpty ? 'Field can\'t empty' : null,
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                    onTap: () => setState(() => _isTapped = true),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.01),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        ),
                      ),
                      contentPadding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                              width: 0.8)),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                              width: 0.8)),
                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7), width: 0.8),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, size: 25),
                      isDense: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  _isTapped && _filteredList.isNotEmpty
                      ? Container(
                          height: 150.0,
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: _filteredList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() => _isTapped = !_isTapped);
                                  widget.textController!.text =
                                      _filteredList[index];
                                setState(() {

                                });
                                },
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                                  child: Text(_filteredList[index],
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                                          fontSize: 16.0)),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                ],
              ))
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made my own which is working. I used the Levenshtein string similarity algorithm, which is great for similar length strings and spell checking but falls a bit short for suggestions. I would recommend swapping this out for something more fit to your use case.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropdownSearch extends StatefulWidget {
  DropdownSearch({
    required this.items,
    required this.tec,
  });

  final List<String> items;
  final TextEditingController tec;
  bool isPopupOpen = false;

  @override
  _DropdownSearchState createState() => _DropdownSearchState();
}

class _DropdownSearchState extends State<DropdownSearch> {
  late GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback callback) {
    super.setState(callback);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textFieldStreamController.add('');
    textFieldStream = textFieldStreamController.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  updatePopupListFilter(String searchString, BuildContext context) {
    if (!widget.isPopupOpen) {
      _showOptionsPopup(
          context, globalKey, widget.items, widget.tec, textFieldStream, () {
        widget.isPopupOpen = false;
      });
      widget.isPopupOpen = true;
    }
    textFieldStreamController.add(searchString);
  }

  List<String> filteredOptions = [];

  StreamController<String> textFieldStreamController =
      StreamController<String>();
  late Stream<String> textFieldStream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          key: globalKey,
          controller: widget.tec,
          onTap: () {
            updatePopupListFilter(widget.tec.text, context);
          },
          onChanged: (newString) {
            textFieldStreamController.add(newString);
            updatePopupListFilter(widget.tec.text, context);
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
            suffixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.search_outlined,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 24.0,
            ),
          ),
          // style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).bodyMedium,
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}

_showOptionsPopup(
  BuildContext context,
  GlobalKey trackedObjectKey,
  List<String> content,
  TextEditingController tec,
  Stream<String> stream,
  Function close,
) {
  final RenderBox renderBox =
      trackedObjectKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  final size = renderBox.size;
  final position = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  double left = position.dx;
  double top = position.dy + size.height;

  late OverlayEntry overlayEntry;
  overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              overlayEntry.remove();
              close();
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            )),
        Positioned(
            top: top + 2,
            left: left,
            child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Container(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: stream,
                    initialData: '',
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Container();
                      } else {
                        List<String> filteredOptions = firstX(
                            6,
                            sortStringsToMatchTarget(
                                snapshot.data as String, content));
                        return ListOptionStringWidgets(
                          options: filteredOptions,
                          onSelectCallback: (stringValue) {
                            tec.text = stringValue;
                            overlayEntry.remove();
                            close();
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ))),
      ],
    );
  });
  Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);
}

List<T> firstX<T>(int count, List<T> vals) {
  if (vals.length < count) {
    return vals;
  }
  List<T> ret = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ret.add(vals[i]);
  }
  return ret;
}

class ListOptionStringWidgets extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListOptionStringWidgets({
    super.key,
    required this.options,
    required this.onSelectCallback,
  });

  final List<String> options;
  final Function(String) onSelectCallback;
  @override
  State<ListOptionStringWidgets> createState() =>
      _ListOptionStringWidgetsState();
}

class _ListOptionStringWidgetsState extends State<ListOptionStringWidgets> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List<Widget>.generate(
        widget.options.length,
        (index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => widget.onSelectCallback(widget.options[index]),
          child: ListTile(
              title: Text(widget.options[index]), tileColor: Colors.grey),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Add the following to the same file or import

```
int measureStringSimilarity(String s, String t, {bool caseSensitive = false}) {
  return levenshteinStringSimilarity(
      s, t); //TODO: Add nicer search criteria. Levenshtein a bit underwhelming
}

int levenshteinStringSimilarity(String s, String t,
    {bool caseSensitive = false}) {
  if (!caseSensitive) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    t = t.toLowerCase();
  }
  if (s == t) return 0;
  if (s.length == 0) return t.length;
  if (t.length == 0) return s.length;

  List<int> v0 = new List<int>.filled(t.length + 1, 0);
  List<int> v1 = new List<int>.filled(t.length + 1, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < t.length + 1; i < i++) v0[i] = i;

  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    v1[0] = i + 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
      int cost = (s[i] == t[j]) ? 0 : 1;
      v1[j + 1] = min(v1[j] + 1, min(v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < t.length + 1; j++) {
      v0[j] = v1[j];
    }
  }

  return v1[t.length];
}

List<String> sortStringsToMatchTarget(String input, List<String> source) {
  List<Map<String, int>> valMap = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    valMap.add({source[i]: measureStringSimilarity(input, source[i])});
  }
  valMap.sort(
    (a, b) => a.values.first.compareTo(b.values.first),
  );
  return List<String>.generate(
      valMap.length, (index) => valMap[index].keys.first);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Those who want a simple-to-use plugin try [this one](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_down_search_field)