# The name of the class 'List' can't be included in a list literal on creating dropdown Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to populate a drop down list from sql server in my flutter app.
I defined a List variable:

```
  List data =List[];
```

which throws me error:

> The name of the class 'List' can't be included in a list literal.

and i am gettin jason data as follows:

```
Future getDriverName() async{
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ROOT), body: {
  "action": 'driverNames',
  "id":prefs.getString('id')!
});
var driverNames = json.decode(response.body);
setState(() {
  data=driverNames;
});
print(driverNames);
return "success";
```

}

and using in Dropdown button as follows:

```
DropdownButton(
                    items: data.map((list) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem(
                        child: new Text(list['item_name']),
                        value: list['id'].toString(),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (newVal) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedName = newVal.toString();
                      });
                    },
                    value: selectedName,
                  ),
```

i am not able to understand the issue becouse i am  new to flutter? please help.
Thanks in advance <3

Comment: If you want put json data to dropdown refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119873/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210)

Comment: `List data =[];`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because can't use **List** keyword when you are using a `literal` but you can define it into a different way like below :

with `literal`

```
List list = [];
```

with `List keyword`

```
List list = List.empty();
```