# DropDownButton: Adjust height of items

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I have DropDownButton:

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    child: DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: true,
      value: value,
      items: widget.items.map((item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: item, 
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
              children: [
                Text(
                  item.toString(),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    item.subtitle.toString(),
                    maxLines: 2,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0)
                ),
              ]),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            )
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      selectedItemBuilder: (context) {
        return widget.items.map((item) {
          return Align(
            child: Text(
              item.toString(),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          );
        }).toList();
      }
    )
  )
```

[image]

I am trying to implement a title and a subtitle (a bit smaller description). The title is generating a "Buttom Overflow" and the subtitle overflows to next item.

Is there a chance to adjust the height according to the required space of its content?

**Edit:**

[Example: DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=352f0a72f9a08fe660decf4e5e2c0bd2)

**Edit:**

To make it clearer: My goal is to allow:

- At least one line title, may allow two lines title
- Optionally up to two lines subtitle

Makes 1-4 lines per item. Height of the item in the list should be adjusted depending on its content.

Comment: please provide a simple runnable code. thanks.

Comment: Refer my answers for long dropdown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119873/13997210) hope its help to you. Or put Your Column Widget inside `SingleChildScollView()` refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210)

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I don't see how your example may help me, sry. The DropDown itself works like charm. For me the second text element in the item element is the problem. It does not adjust the height. Which part of your examples fix that?

Comment: Can you provide list of item , so can run and check

Comment: If you display title and subtitle so used ListTile widget

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil you mean instead of Container(child: Column: ... )?

Comment: @S-Man refer my below answer

Comment: @HardikMehta See edit for example

Comment: @reza See edit for example

Answer (score 3):

Try below code hope its help to you. Refer **`ListTile`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

```
String? sid;
  List data = [];
  var urls = "https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas";
```

Your API call function:

```
Future fetchData() async {
    var result = await http.get(Uri.parse(urls), headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    });
    var jsonData = json.decode(result.body);

    setState(() {
      data = jsonData;
    });
    return jsonData;
  }
```

call your API fetchData() inside initState()

```
@override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Your Dropdown Widget:

```
Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    width: 200,
    height: 70,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
        20,
      ),
    ),
    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
        isDense: true,
        isExpanded: true,
        value: sid,
        hint: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            "Select Data",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        items: data.map((list) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(list['nome']),
              subtitle: Text(list['nome']),
            ),  
            value: list['codigo'].toString(),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            sid = value as String?;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Result screen for dropdown button -> [image]

Result Screen for Dropdown list-> [image]

Result screen after selected dropdown item-> [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvdCA.png It only removes the "bottom overflow" error, but overlapping still exists. (Btw: change ´subTitle´ to ´subtitle´)

Comment: can you share your url?

Comment: Of course, but does not know if it's helpful, because it's a huge project... https://github.com/S-Man42/GCWizard/blob/2.2.0/lib/widgets/common/base/gcw_dropdownbutton.dart

Comment: @S-Man check my updated answer I have used dummy data

Comment: Sorry, still no effect. Only difference I see in the code is the `isDense: true`. But that makes no difference. Does your code still work if the texts are longer and result in line breaks?

Comment: Yes its working for me please see the result image

Comment: I mean, two-line titles and subtitles... In your result image I can see one-liner for both ;) That works for me too. My problem is when the texts getting larger

Comment: As you can see here: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=0497b7a654d29b89450745407f50b291 With your code, multi line titles/subtitles don't work anyway

Comment: @S-Man please check my updated answer and let me know your problem is solved or not.

Comment: If I am correct, you changed the layout of the button now, not of the menu item list. My button is fine. Please see the example in dartpad: I want 2 lines for both, title and subtitle (means 4 lines per item). You have one line for both.

Answer (score 3):

You can change dropdown item height with [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2). Use `itemHeight` Property to do that.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the package mentioned above.

Comment: Althought I really don't want to use an external dependency for such a core feature, can you provide an example where itemHeight depends on its widget. Sometimes title is a one-liner, sometimes more. Subtitle is sometimes existing, sometimes not....

Comment: I don't like using too many external dependencies but I've found that DropdownButton lacks to many features so I've made that package. It's the same as Flutter's core DropdownButton but more customizable so It has the same performance.

Comment: For dynamic itemHeight that would affect the dropdown performance which could hold long list. Flutter's DropdownButton hardcoded the height to _kMenuItemHeight. While I've made an option to change the height by using itemHeight property, I've also Added an option to add secondary different height for things like dividers. You can use it for your items with subtitle to give them different height. see the example with the package for adding dividers with different height.

Comment: Ok, I see. But this is not what I really need. I need to put in a widget of any kind (in my example a Column with two Text widgets) and need to stretch the height according to the widget size. As it is done in Lists or any other place... My problem is, that I don't know the count of lines beforehand. It depends on localization and such things. I can't say: CustomHeight = X. For some languages X may become too huge, for some too small. I'd like to see a solution for more flexibility. Do you believe, it is possible?

Comment: You can make your own custom dropdown to achieve that but I'm not sure if that would be good in performance. Another solution is to make the Height a little big for some x lines and give the description maxLines value and TextOverflow.ellipsis.

Comment: I am using DropdownButton2 it is very useful, especially for its searching capabilities, well done Ahmed.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Nav2App());
}

class Nav2App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String? sid;
  List data = [{"nome":"Acura Acura Acura Acura ","codigo":"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1"},
               {"nome":"Agrale Agrale","codigo":" 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 "}
              ];
  
  
  PageController _scrollController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          child: InputDecorator(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton(
                isDense: true,
                isExpanded: true,
                value: sid,
                hint: Text("Select Data",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                items: data.map((item) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            item['nome'].toString(),
                          ),
                          Flexible( child:Container(
                            child:  Text(
                              item['codigo'].toString(),
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0)
                          ),),
                        ]),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      ),
                    value: item['codigo'].toString(),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    sid = value as String?;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

just wrap second `Container` of `Column` for subtitle with `Flexible` widget.

[image]

Edited:
for multiline title and subtitle:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Nav2App());
}

class Nav2App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  String? sid;
  List data = [
    {
      "nome": "Acura Acura Acura Acura Acura Acura Acura",
      "codigo": "1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 12 76 7 8 9 22 23 34 45"
    },
    {
      "nome": "Agrale Agrale",
      "codigo": " 8 9 10 11 12 2 23 34 56 78 90 11 12 34"
    }
  ];

  PageController _scrollController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 250,
            child: InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton(
                  itemHeight: 70,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  isDense: true,
                  value: sid,
                  hint: Text("Select Data",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  items: data.map((item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text(
                              item['nome'].toString(),
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text(
                              item['codigo'].toString(),
                              maxLines: 2,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      value: item['codigo'].toString(),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      sid = value as String?;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

let me know if its works for you or not.

Comment: I tried this as well, but as you can see, then I have no line wrap anymore. My goal is to allow at least 2 lines for title and subtitle.

Comment: @S-Man : Please check my answer with Edited  label.Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the itemHeight. I guess, that would be the best workaround, but not the final solution I wished. It seems impossible to get a flexible item height, isn't it (see the empty line in your second example, I would like to avoid it...). Thanks for your effort!