# The value of my dropdown list is changing whenever I type something in my textfield in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have some textfields and some dropdowns in my page. I am fetching the list of my dropdowns from APIs. I made a custom widget for drop down buttons. Now, when I am selecting a value from drop down and then typing something in my textfield, I am getting an error. I think, my futurebuilder is running everytime I select/deselect textfield. How can I stop this?

Here is a snippet of my code -

```
class AddLeadsScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final String? phoneNumber;
  final String? countryCode;

  const AddLeadsScreen({Key? key, this.phoneNumber, this.countryCode}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddLeadsScreen> createState() => _AddLeadsScreenState();
}

class _AddLeadsScreenState extends State<AddLeadsScreen> {

  Future<List<BranchModel>>? branches;
  Future<List<AcademicYearListItemModal>>? academicList;
  Future<List<GradeModal>>? gradeList;
  Future<List<ContactSource>>? contactList;

  @override
  initState() {
    branches = fetchBranch();
    academicList = fetchAcademicYear();
    gradeList = fetchGradeList();
    contactList = fetchContactSourceList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: regularAppBar(context: context, title: "Add Lead"),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(16),
        ),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            .........
            FutureBuilder(
              future: academicList,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AcademicYearListItemModal>> snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.connectionState!=ConnectionState.done) {
                  return const Text("Please wait...");
                }
                else if(snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Text("Error");
                }
                else if(snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                  return const Text("No data");
                }
                else {
                  List<AcademicYearListItemModal> list =
                      snapshot.data ?? [];
                  List<FilterListDataModel> modelList = [];
                  for (var element in list) {
                    if (element.sessionYear != null) {
                      modelList.add(FilterListDataModel(
                          text: element.sessionYear, id: element.id));
                    }
                  }
                  return AddLeadDetailDropDown(
                    title: "Academic Year",
                    menuItems: modelList,
                    hint: "Select",
                    border: true,
                    changeVal: (val) {
                      academicYear = val.text;
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            const AddLeadDetailTextField(
              title: "Lead name",
              hint: "Enter lead name",
              border: true,
            ),
            ........
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are my custom widgets:

Dropdown button -

```
class AddLeadDetailDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? title;
  final List<FilterListDataModel>? menuItems;
  final String? hint;
  final bool? haveFistValue;
  final bool? border;
  final ValueChanged? changeVal;

  const AddLeadDetailDropDown(
      {Key? key,
      this.title,
      this.menuItems,
      this.hint,
      this.haveFistValue,
      this.border,
      this.changeVal})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddLeadDetailDropDown> createState() => _AddLeadDetailDropDownState();
}

class _AddLeadDetailDropDownState extends State<AddLeadDetailDropDown> {
  FilterListDataModel? dropDownValue;
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>? list;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.title ?? "",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(16),
                color: const Color(0XFF666666),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              '*',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: getProportionateScreenHeight(4),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            color: textFieldBackground,
            border: widget.border == true && dropDownValue != null
                ? Border.all(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5))
                : null,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(12),
          ),
          child: DropdownButton<FilterListDataModel>(
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                dropDownValue = val;
              });
              if (widget.changeVal != null) {
                widget.changeVal!(val);
              }
            },
            items: widget.menuItems?.map<DropdownMenuItem<FilterListDataModel>>(
                (FilterListDataModel value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<FilterListDataModel>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value.text ?? ""),
              );
            }).toList(),
            value: dropDownValue,
            underline: const SizedBox(),
            hint: widget.hint != null
                ? Text(
                    widget.hint!,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      color: hintTextColor,
                    ),
                  )
                : null,
            isExpanded: true,
            iconDisabledColor: const Color(0XFF999999),
            iconEnabledColor: dropDownValue != null
                ? Colors.black87
                : const Color(0XFF999999),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Custom Textfield -

```
class AddLeadDetailTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? title;
  final bool? border;
  final String? hint;
  final String? val;
  final ValueChanged? changeVal;

  const AddLeadDetailTextField(
      {Key? key, this.title, this.border, this.hint, this.val, this.changeVal})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddLeadDetailTextField> createState() => _AddLeadDetailTextFieldState();
}

class _AddLeadDetailTextFieldState extends State<AddLeadDetailTextField> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  bool isVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.text = widget.val ?? "";
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.title ?? "",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(16),
                color: const Color(0XFF666666),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              '*',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: getProportionateScreenHeight(4),
        ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            color: textFieldBackground,
            border: widget.border == true && isVisible
                ? Border.all(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5))
                : null,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(12),
          ),
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.hint,
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: hintTextColor,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 16),
            onChanged: (val) {
              if (val != "") {
                setState(() {
                  isVisible = true;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  isVisible = false;
                });
              }
              if (widget.changeVal != null) {
                widget.changeVal!(val);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Error -

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building AddLeadDetailDropDown(dirty, state: _AddLeadDetailDropDownState#09a24):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'FilterListDataModel'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AddLeadDetailDropDown AddLeadDetailDropDown:file:///C:/Users/Hp/AndroidStudioProjects/K12/crm-app/lib/screens/manage_leads/add_lead_screen.dart:94:26
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new DropdownButton (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:882:15)
#3      _AddLeadDetailDropDownState.build (package:crmapp/ui_components/drop_downs/add_lead_detail_drop_down.dart:75:18)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#8      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#11     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#13     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#15     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#25     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#28     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#30     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#32     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#33     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#34     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#36     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1265:37)
#37     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1169:35)
#38     Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:325:35)
#39     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1213:24)
#40     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1146:7)
#41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#44     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#45     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#46     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#47     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#48     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5825:32)
#49     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#50     _ViewportElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/viewport.dart:237:11)
#51     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#52     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#54     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#55     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#56     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#58     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#59     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#60     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#61     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#62     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#63     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#64     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#65     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#66     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#67     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#68     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#69     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#70     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#71     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#72     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#73     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#74     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#75     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#76     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#77     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#78     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#79     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#80     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#81     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#82     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#83     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#84     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#85     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#86     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#87     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#88     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#89     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#90     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#91     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#92     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#93     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#94     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#95     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#96     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#97     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#98     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#99     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#100    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#101    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#102    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#103    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#104    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#105    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#106    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#107    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#108    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#109    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4883:5)
#110    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#111    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#112    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#113    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#114    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#115    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#116    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#117    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#118    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#119    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5825:32)
#120    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6375:17)
#121    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#122    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#123    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#124    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#125    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#126    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#127    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#128    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#129    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#130    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#131    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#132    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#133    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#134    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#135    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#136    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#137    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#138    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#139    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#140    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#141    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#142    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6222:14)
#143    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#144    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#145    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#146    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#147    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#148    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#149    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#150    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#151    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#152    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#153    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#154    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#155    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#156    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#157    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#158    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#159    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#160    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#161    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#162    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#163    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#164    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#165    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#166    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#167    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#168    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#169    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5154:5)
#170    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#171    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
#172    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#173    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#174    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5009:5)
#175    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3530:15)
#176    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:16)
```

Comment: If you want to get data from API and display it into flutter dropdown refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119873/13997210)

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I would really appreciate if you can answer the question that I asked. Please don't put random comments.