# How to use API in Dropdown list in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, dropdown

[Output in Working Condtion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lAY2.jpg)
Hello Flutter/Dart Programmers, I'm new in Flutter. below code about Dropdown is working without API, but i wants API data to display in Dropdown list.... i need help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DropDownButton',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String selectValue = "";
  List categoryItemlist = [];

  //List categoryItemlist = List();  //it is not working

  // ***********************************************************
  // Fetch data from JSON/API File
  Future getAllCategory() async {
    var baseUrl = "https://gssskhokhar.com/api/classes/";

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        categoryItemlist = jsonData;
      });
    }
    print(categoryItemlist);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllCategory();
  }
  // ***********************************************************

// Initial Selected Value
  String dropdownvalue = 'Item 1';

// List of items in our dropdown menu
  var items = [
    'Item 1',
    'Item 2',
    'Item 3',
    'Item 4',
    'Item 5',
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("DropDown List"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            DropdownButton(
              // Initial Value
              value: dropdownvalue,

              // Down Arrow Icon
              icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

              // Array list of items
              items: items.map((String items) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: items,
                  child: Text(items),
                );
              }).toList(),
              // After selecting the desired option,it will
              // change button value to selected value
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output Pic is attach with working condition but without API/JSON. but i wants API data to display in Dropdown list....

Comment: refer this answers- [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71995826/13997210), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119873/13997210), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68735915/13997210)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need this codes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DropDownButton',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List categoryItemlist = [];

  Future getAllCategory() async {
    var baseUrl = "https://gssskhokhar.com/api/classes/";

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        categoryItemlist = jsonData;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllCategory();
  }

  var dropdownvalue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("DropDown List"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            DropdownButton(
              hint: Text('hooseNumber'),
              items: categoryItemlist.map((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: item['ClassCode'].toString(),
                  child: Text(item['ClassName'].toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newVal) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue = newVal;
                });
              },
              value: dropdownvalue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it is too working dear.... now next how can i send/print a selected value ? actually now i wanna next dropdown depends on Class selected value...

Comment: onChanged (newVal) {
setstate((){
print(newVal);
})  
}

Comment: second question that you asked is Complicated please post it i answer it for you with codes

Comment: Hello @4rmin see the code

https://www.gssskhokhar.com/api/main.txt

i created getClassSelectedValue(newVal); function

and another Dropdown...

now i wants, after selection class, its name go to another Dropdown (2nd Dropdown)

via this api 

https://gssskhokhar.com/api/classes/$getClassCode

Answer (score 6):

Use `FutureBuilder` to build widgets which requires `Future` value.

You can return new list of `DropDownMenuIems` from your `getAllCategory()` method Instead of updating old Items.
Like:

```
Future<List<String>> getAllCategory() async {
    var baseUrl = "https://gssskhokhar.com/api/classes/";

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<String> items = [];
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      for (var element in jsonData) {
        items.add(element["ClassName"]);
      }
      return items;
    } else {
      //Handle Errors
      throw response.statusCode;
    }
  }
```

Then you can give `getAllCategory()` as future of `FutureBuilder`. `FutureBuilder` will build different widgets according to the provided `Future`. you can return `CircularProgressIndicator` until future doesn't have value. After getting your `DropDownMenuItems` you can return your `DropDownMenu`. Like:

```
           FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
              future: getAllCategory(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var data = snapshot.data!;
                  return DropdownButton(
                    // Initial Value
                    value: dropdownvalue ?? data[0],

                    // Down Arrow Icon
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                    // Array list of items
                    items: data.map((String items) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: items,
                        child: Text(items),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    // After selecting the desired option,it will
                    // change button value to selected value
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )
```

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DropDownButton',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? dropdownvalue;

  Future<List<String>> getAllCategory() async {
    var baseUrl = "https://gssskhokhar.com/api/classes/";

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<String> items = [];
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      for (var element in jsonData) {
        items.add(element["ClassName"]);
      }
      return items;
    } else {
      throw response.statusCode;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("DropDown List"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
              future: getAllCategory(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var data = snapshot.data!;
                  return DropdownButton(
                    // Initial Value
                    value: dropdownvalue ?? data[0],

                    // Down Arrow Icon
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),

                    // Array list of items
                    items: data.map((String items) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: items,
                        child: Text(items),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    // After selecting the desired option,it will
                    // change button value to selected value
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

hello brother i am so busy this days i watch your codes i know what you want

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DropDownButton',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List categoryItemlist = [];

  Future getAllCategory() async {
    var baseUrl = "https://gssskhokhar.com/api/classes/";

    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        categoryItemlist = jsonData;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllCategory();
  }

  var dropdownvalue;
  var dropdownvalueSubject;
  var subjectItemlist = [];

  Future getSubjects(getClassCode) async {
    var baseUrlSubject = "https://gssskhokhar.com/api/classes/$getClassCode";
    http.Response responseSubject = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrlSubject));
    if (responseSubject.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonDataSubject = json.decode(responseSubject.body);
      setState(() {
        subjectItemlist.add(jsonDataSubject);
        print(subjectItemlist);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("DropDown List"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            DropdownButton(
              hint: Text('Select Class'),
              items: categoryItemlist.map((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: item['ClassCode'].toString(),
                  child: Text(item['ClassName'].toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newVal) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalue = newVal;
                  getSubjects(dropdownvalue);
                });
              },
              value: dropdownvalue,
            ),
            DropdownButton(
              hint: Text('Selected Class Code Here'),
              items: subjectItemlist.map((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: item['ClassCode'].toString(),
                  child: Text(item['ClassName'].toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newValSubject) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownvalueSubject = newValSubject;
                });
              },
              value: dropdownvalueSubject,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i hope it help you