# How to bind Api Data in dropdown button and get selected Value?

Tags: flutter, api

How to bind Api Data in dropdown button and get selected Value?

I have json rsponse as below.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "standard": [
    {
      "standard_id": "5d170c1e3ba1c",
      "standard_name": "Std 10",
      "active": "1"
    },
    {
      "standard_id": "5da9f8652dfd3",
      "standard_name": "Std 10 Easy Maths Course",
      "active": "1"
    },
    {
      "standard_id": "5d170c5a5609a",
      "standard_name": "Std 12 Science - A ( PCM Full Course )",
      "active": "1"
    },
    {
      "standard_id": "5da9fa1fd7e60",
      "standard_name": "Std 12 Science - B ( PCB Full Course ) ",
      "active": "1"
    },
    {
      "standard_id": "5ea96da290df1",
      "standard_name": "Std 12 Science Chemistry Course",
      "active": "1"
    },
    {
      "standard_id": "5ea96d89c8978",
      "standard_name": "Std 12 Science Maths Course",
      "active": "1"
    },
    {
      "standard_id": "5ea96db6adbc0",
      "standard_name": "Std 12 Science Physics Course",
      "active": "1"
    },
    {
      "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
      "standard_name": "Std 2",
      "active": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

As above response i created a Model class as below in standard_model.dart file.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final standardModel = standardModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

StandardModel standardModelFromJson(String str) => StandardModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String standardModelToJson(StandardModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class StandardModel {
    StandardModel({
        this.success,
        this.standard,
    });

    int success;
    List<Standard> standard;

    factory StandardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => StandardModel(
        success: json["success"],
        standard: List<Standard>.from(json["standard"].map((x) => Standard.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "standard": List<dynamic>.from(standard.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Standard {
    Standard({
        this.standardId,
        this.standardName,
        this.active,
    });

    String standardId;
    String standardName;
    String active;

    factory Standard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Standard(
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        standardName: json["standard_name"],
        active: json["active"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "standard_name": standardName,
        "active": active,
    };
}
```

I created Function in api_manager.dart file as below

```
class ApiManager {
  Future<List<Standard>> getStandards() async {
    final standardUrl = "$baseUrl/standard/get";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(standardUrl));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final standardData = standardModelFromJson(response.body);
      final List<Standard> standards = standardData.standard;
      return standards;
    } else {
      return <Standard>[];
    }
  }
}
```

And i have view.dart file to show dropdown, so how i can set data in dropdown button and get selected value.

view.dart file as below.

```
class View extends StatefulWidget {
  const View({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewState createState() => _ViewState();
}

class _ViewState extends State<View> {
  var _standards = <Standard>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ApiManager().getStandards().then((standards) {
      _standards = standards;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButton(
              isExpanded: true,
              hint: Text('Select Standard'),
              value: ,
              items: ,
              onChanged: , //onStandardChange,
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i want to get  standard names in dropdownlist.

Comment: you should use FutureBuilder widget.

Comment: i tried it but when i used map with snapshot.data it not works.

Comment: can you please provide reference code.?

Comment: try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) hope it helps to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need to use `Column`. you should follow this code:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue, // create a variable named dropdownValue and set in onChange function
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: _standards
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((Standard standard) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: standard.standardId,
          child: Text(standard.standardName),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

Also keep in mind that instead of using `DropdownButton<String>` you can use `DropdownButton<Standard>`. for further detail see [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).
check it out and let me know the result.

Comment: need to use FutureBuilder?

Comment: Sir, if you have any reference for login with api using model class then please provide.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your question. please create a new question, give your codes, and tag me in its comment.  I will check it out and let you know.