# Can I get multiple return from dropdownbutton?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to make json to dropdownbutton today.

But I want to get 2 values(ID and Name both) from it.

this is my json

> [{"StudentID":"3","StudentName":"Amy"},{"StudentID":"4","StudentName":"Derek"}]

and this is my code of dropdown button.

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:5),
              child: new DropdownButton(
                value: _StudentSelection,
                items: StudentData.map((product) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: product["StudentID"].toString(),
                      child: new Text(product["StudentName"]!)
                  )
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _StudentSelection = newValue!;
                  });
                },
                hint: Text('StudentID'),
              )
          ),
          ],
        ),
```

in this case variety _StudentSelection is already initialized by Amy and StudentData is result of decoding json.

Thank you for seeing this question :)

Comment: Can you add an error message?

Comment: @SalihCan there is no error. but in this case I can get only a value from it.

Comment: you want to display id and name also in this dropdown?

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil No. display is okay, But i just want to store 2 values in my variety

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Thanks for kind comment :-3

Comment: @Malone your problem is solved by answer?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Yes. it helped me a lot. thank you!

Comment: @Malone most welcome glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Make your `_StudentSelection` variable's type the same type as your `product` variable and then use `product` as a `value:`, not just the ID.

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:5),
              child: new DropdownButton(
                value: _StudentSelection, // change this variables type to the type of your product variable
                items: StudentData.map((product) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: product, // use the whole product as value
                      child: new Text(product["StudentName"]!)
                  )
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (TYPE_OF_PRODUCT_HERE? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _StudentSelection = newValue!;
                  });
                },
                hint: Text('StudentID'),
              )
          ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: At this time, how can I initialize variable?  String is easy, but I don't think anything right now.

Comment: What do you want to initialize it to? I don't even know what type it is.