# Flutter Dropdown List Issue

Tags: flutter

I have one phpmysql database. And i am fetching data from database. And i wanna showing my categories data into my dropdown button. But its showing only first data. Thats my code.

```
SizedBox(
                                width: context.dynamicWidth(5),
                                height: context.dynamicHeight(5),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: snap.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    var categoryList =
                                        snap[index]['categoryName'];
                                    return DropdownButton<String>(
                                      items: <String>[
                                        categoryList,
                                      ].map((String value) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: value,
                                          child: Text(value),
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),
                                      onChanged: (_) {},
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
```

Thats show only first data. Thx for helping.

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) hope its help to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your snap list type but hope this work's

```
SizedBox(
                                width: context.dynamicWidth(5),
                                height: context.dynamicHeight(5),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: snap.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return DropdownButton<String>(
                                      items: snap.map((value) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: value['categoryName'],
                                          child:Text(value['categoryName']),
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),
                                      onChanged: (_) {},
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
```

Comment: Thats working. Thx. U are perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    var categoryList = snap[index];
```

instead of

```
    var categoryList = snap[index]['categoryName'];
```

Comment: Sorry not working. Thats showing that  https://ibb.co/whQDQHP

Comment: ```return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: value['categoryName'],
                                          child: Text(value),
                                        );```

Comment: Sorry still same :(