# call API parameters into dropdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

i have data api as follows and also in that api have a parameter,
so I want to call parameters into dropdown to show to user.
how can i do that?
can anyone provide an example
I've been looking for ways but I haven't found a solution yet

[image]

and I want to call the parameter in dropdown

[image]

this is when i fetch the data

```
Future<NilaiMahasiswa> getNilaiMahasiswa(int semester) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/transkrip_nilai?semester=$semester',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

and in this list I want to convert the data into parameters in the API

```
List<String> listitems = [
    "United States of America",
    "Canada",
    "United Kingdom",
    "China",
    "Russia",
    "Austria"
  ];

  String selectval = "United States of America";
  List<Data> data = [];
```

...

```
Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 8),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 9,
                    offset: const Offset(
                      1,
                      2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton(
                  value: selectval,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectval = value.toString();
                    });
                  },
                  items: listitems.map((itemone) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: itemone, child: Text(itemone));
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68418476/13997210) for getting json data from API and display it dropdown

Comment: I'm a little confused with the code you provided

Comment: maybe can you be more specific with the code above, I've tried but found some errors

Comment: Hi, if I understood correctly, you want to show information about semester which fetched from api that choosen from dropdown, right?

Comment: Yes, it is true

Comment: can you show me what have you done for information showing part? I can modify it